# Creating a simple multi tab form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-shell

[image: System Properties]
I need something like this, the image list several tabs each when clicked takes you to its respective form within the window, I just need the look and feel of something like this.
But instead of stacking tabs horizontally I need them stacked up vertically. I just need 3 multiple forms in 3 different tabs. I want the basic look and feel like the *System Properties* window when you right click *My Computer* → *Properties*.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck? (See also the http://stackoverflow.com/faq about asking questions on SO. ;-)

Comment: @stakx:I want the look and feel of something like this, I am new using Winforms I need some start. Apreciate your quick response. Tx

Comment: You cannot expect others to solve your problems *completely*... but that's exactly what your question suggests since you're only stating what you *want*, and not what you've *tried*. If you have *no* prior experience with Winforms, then I suggest that you first learn a bit about it, then try for yourself, and *then* come back here with specific questions. If you *do* have some experience with Winforms, then surely you've already tried a few things by yourself and run into a more specific problem...?

Comment: @stakx- Thanks but all I need is basic design. I will work on it and let you know where I get with it.Thanks again.

Comment: @stakx: I have got the layout figured out, after adding tabs to the main window which is sized at 675x627, After clicking each tab I want a form displayed within its page, here my tabpage is sized at 621x333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TabControl has a property called 'Alignment' with four possible enum-values (Top, Left, Right, Bottom). By default the value is set to Top but if you set it to Left, the tabs will appear on the left side of the TabControl.

```
YourTabControl.Alignment = TabAlignment.Left;
```

Comment: I have got the basic layout, but when I click each tab the form is displayed outside the actual window, is there any wrapperclass to help me display the form inside the tab page.

Comment: Why would you use a Form to achieve this? Just place your controls inside one of the tabitems.